# An Alternative Approach for Broadcast stream

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have two different streams in my flink job;

- First one is representing set of rules which will be applied to the actual stream. I've just broadcasted these set of rules. Changes are come from kafka, and there can be a few changes each hour (like 100-200 per hour).
- Second one is actual stream called as customer stream which contains some numeric values for each customer. This is basically keyed stream based on customerId.

So, basically I'm preparing my actual customer stream data, then applying `some rules` on keyed stream, and getting the calculated results.

And, I also know which rules should be calculated by checking a field of customer stream data. For example; a field of customer data contains value `X`, that means job have to apply only `rule1, rule2, rule5` instead of calculating all the rules (let's say there are 90 rules) for the given customer. Of course, in this case, I have to get and filter all rules by field value of incoming data.

Everything is ok in this scenario, and perfectly fits broadcast pattern usage. But the problem here is that huge broadcast size. Sometimes it can be very huge, like 20 GB or more. It supposes it's very huge for broadcast state.

Is there any alternative approach to solve this limitation? Like, using rocks db backend (I know it's not supported, but I can implement custom state backend for broadcast state if there is no limitation about this).

Is there any changes if I connect both streams without broadcasting rules stream?

Answer (score 3):

From your description it sounds like you might be able to avoid broadcasting the rules (by turning this around and broadcasting the primary stream to the rules). Maybe this could work:

1. make sure each incoming customer event has a unique ID
2. key-partition the rules so that each rule has a distinct key
3. broadcast the primary stream events to the rules (and don't store the customer events)
4. union the outputs from applying all the rules
5. keyBy the unique ID from step (1) to bring together the results from applying each of the rules to a given customer event, and assemble a unified result

https://gist.github.com/alpinegizmo/5d5f24397a6db7d8fabc1b12a15eeca6 shows how to do fan-out/fan-in with Flink -- see that for an example of steps 1, 4, and 5 above.

Comment: Yeah, sometimes thinking opposite of the current solution is necessary! I'm going to look into this solution. Thank you so much!

Comment: I also have one more question. would it be problem to broadcast one stream and store the data into rocksdb by accessing keyed stream state? this is like duplicating broadcast data for each key without storing broadcast data in memory

Comment: In the `processBroadcastElement` method you can store the arriving broadcast event in broadcast state. And you can also iterate over all of the keyed state in each instance (over all existing keys) and delete/update that state in whatever way you want. But you cannot insert state for non-existing keys (because you can't (easily) tell if any particular key should be present in any particular instance). https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.apache.flink.streaming.api.functions.co.KeyedBroadcastProcessFunction$Context/applyToKeyedState has an example.

Comment: Hi, again me, just one more question; as solution you offered, let's say parallelism is 4 in a task manager. So, will the event of the main stream be processed by just one task in a task manager? I'm actually curios that does `processBroadcastElement` method is called in each task or not

Comment: `ctx.applyToKeyedState` is probably getting each keyed state in the task manager, and apply the function that we provided. But parallelism is also important here as I've asked. So, if I have 1000 events that have to be processed, I'll send 1000 events to the each task manager (each task manager also have 4 cores), so each task manager will process 1000 events in 4 parallelism by dividing keyed streams into 4. Is that correct or am I missing something?

Comment: Yes, you've got that right. `processBroadcastElement` is called in every parallel instance across all of the TMs. And if you use `ctx.applyToKeyedState` it is applied to the state for every key present in each instance.

Comment: Thank you much! So, I'm also wondering that is there any way to write custom backend like using local file system for broadcast state?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no way to partition the rules dataset, then I don't think you get a win by trying to connect streams.

I would check out [Apache Ignite](https://ignite.apache.org/) as a way of sharing the rules across all of the subtasks processing the customer stream. See [this article](https://nussknacker.io/blog/apache-ignite-in-nussknacker-environment-lessons-learned/) for a description of how this could be one.