# Flink connect keyed and non keyed streams

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

What happens if I connect keyed and non keyed streams in Flink? For example;

```
val stream1 = source.keyBy(_.customerId)
val stream2 = source2.map(operation()...)

stream1.connect(stream2).process(processData).addSink(kafkaSink)
```

The situation here is that I'm trying to apply set of rules (non keyed stream, stream2) to another stream (stream1), I'm normally broadcasting rules stream but the size of the broadcast is getting bigger and bigger. So, I'd just like to learn that what happens if I don't broadcast one of the streams and connect them in terms of parallelism, state etc.?

Comment: If you share your requirements for state and describe how the rules relate to the events in stream1, perhaps we can help you find a workable solution.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! Here is the case detailed in this question; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73255949/an-alternative-approach-for-broadcast-stream
I was just trying to solve this problem by not using external cache like redis

Answer (score 1):

When you connect two streams, they must fall into one of these cases:

1. One of the streams is broadcast
2. Neither stream is keyed
3. Both streams are keyed into the same keyspace

You cannot connect a keyed stream to a non-keyed stream, because the resulting connection won't be key-partitioned.